# cannot install python in windows 64

Tags: python

I tried to install python and add it in path variable, but when I run `python -v` it displays this in command line.

I think the environment variable has something to do with this.

```
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import sys # builtin
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'nt' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'winreg' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-35.pyc'
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\__pycache__\codecs.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\codecs.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\__pycache__\\codecs.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000000000092E320>
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\__pycache__\aliases.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\aliases.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\aliases.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000000009420F0>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000000009249E8>
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\__pycache__\mbcs.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\mbcs.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\mbcs.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.mbcs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000000000959048>
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\__pycache__\utf_8.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\utf_8.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\utf_8.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000000009594A8>
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\latin_1.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\latin_1.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000000000959748>
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\__pycache__\io.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\io.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\__pycache__\\io.cpython-35.pyc'
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\abc.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\__pycache__\\abc.cpython-35.pyc'
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\__pycache__\_weakrefset.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\_weakrefset.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\__pycache__\\_weakrefset.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_weakrefset' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000000000961400>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000000000959BE0>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000000000959978>
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\__pycache__\_bootlocale.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\_bootlocale.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\__pycache__\\_bootlocale.cpython-35.pyc'
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_bootlocale' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x00000000009679B0>
# C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\__pycache__\cp1252.cpython-35.pyc matches C:\Users\abdessamad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\abdessamad\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\cp1252.cpython-35.pyc'
import 'encodings.cp1252' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000000000096
```

7E48>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `python.exe --help`:

```
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
```

So basically, that's what it's meant to display.

If you intended for it to display the version of Python, you need a capital v:

```
python.exe -V
```

Comment: @Abde Samad No problem, just remember to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

solved !! i was typing -v instead -V